# Как сделать функцию счетчик? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужна функция-счетчик, которая сохраняет свое значение в переменную, а потом при вызове еще раз изменяет эту переменную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать глобальную переменную, но вообще их надо использовать аккуратно:

```
s = 0
def func():
    global s
    s += 1
    return None
```

Здесь при каждом запуске функции счетчик будет увеличиваться на 1, таким образом написав `print(s)` в конце-можно узнать сколько раз запускалась функция `func()`.

Answer (score 2):

Всё-таки использовать глобальные переменные без явной нужды - не очень хорошо.

Если вам нужна функция, которая между вызовами должна сохранять какое-то состояние, то почти всегда стоит это делать через классы:

```
class CounterFunction:

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    
    def __call__(self):
        self.counter += 1


func = CounterFunction()

func()
func()
func()

print(func.counter)  # Выведет: 3
```